# Arba'a Asar Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred fourteen?

### ?ארבעה עשר ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 314.

Lazy gematria has to be stopped, lest it grow indefinitely.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred thirteen entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: Should have posted this last thursday on Pi Day! (Which is also the birthday of one of the most famous Jews who ever lived.)

Comment: @DoubleAA, Pi Day is two months after Erev Pesach, leminyanenu.

Comment: AKA Pesach Shelishi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to Yalkut:

```
ר' ינאי אומר לא העבידו המצריים את ישראל אלא שעה אחת מיומו של הקב"ה - שמונים ושש שנה`
```

So 314, out of the promised 400, Am Yisrael was under the impression of the *Galus* but not under hard oppression.

([From](http://www.ladaat.info/Gilionot/20130112/%5B127%5D%D7%91%D7%97%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%95%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%90.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

When one is praying on the [Hithadoo Island in the Maldives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hithadhoo_%28Addu%29) the direction he should Daven per those that Daven following a Great Circle would be [314° North-West](http://www.myzmanim.com/day.aspx?lang=en&vars=44383468).

Comment: "Le-Hithadoo" - to make much of oneself?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I thought it meant: to say goodbye to oneself.